# When creating an array of objects, do the objects in the array all point to the same address?

Tags: java, arrays, reference

I've created an array of these objects that contain a point and an index number. I'm assigning them via Scanner like so:

```
Points[] pointStorage = new Points[10];
pointStorage[index] = new Points(0,0,index);
index++;
while (s.hasNext()) { // s is the Scanner
    double point1 = s.nextDouble(); // X-Coordinate
    double point2 = s.nextDouble();
    pointStorage[index] = new Points(point1,point2,index);
    index++;
}
pointStorage[index] = new Points(0,0,index);
```

I have a method that basically shows the contents all of the objects:

```
for (int i = 0; i < pointStorage.length; i++){
    pointStorage[i].showPoint();
}
```

which outputs (as an example):

```
The X co-ordinate is 0.0
The Y co-ordinate is 0.0
```

However, it appears in my program that all of the objects in the array have been assigned the values from the last created object (point 0,0). Is there a particular reason why? I thought creating new addresses for each one would prevent this.

EDIT:

OK guys, so I found out the problem. Apparently I had set the field (Sorry if that terminology is wrong, I'm new to OOP) for Point2D.Double (what the method "showPoint" displays) to static and apparently that was the problem. I removed the static modifier and now it works fine. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: The code you posted seems to be ok-ish. You have a problem somewhere else. Try to debug it more thoroughly (print out all the values in the process to pinpoint the problem), double-check your input then show us more code.

Comment: @user2757885 - No problem. Glad you fixed it. Please post your solution as an answer and then accept it as correct to close the question.

Comment: @bitfiddler - Since my reputation is below 10, I cannot give an answer until 8 hours after my initial post. I will post an answer at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `new` within the `while` loop. You have created the array of 10 points and should itererate using the `index`.

Make sure to set `index` to 0 beore the loop and you should test for array boundry on each loop.

Consider using a `for` loop and `break` out when the scanner returns false.

```
for( index = 0; index < MAX; index ++ ) {
  if( ! s.hasNext() )
    break;
  double point1 = s.nextDouble(); // X-Coordinate
  double point2 = s.nextDouble();
  Points[index] = Point( point1, point2, index);          
}
```

This is just a rough example to get you started. Have fun...

Comment: This avoids the potential `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, but OP doesn't (yet) get one. I don't think it fixes the problem. Or does it?

Answer (score 0):

OK guys, so I found out the problem. Apparently I had set the field (Sorry if that terminology is wrong, I'm new to OOP) for the Point2D.Double object (what the method "showPoint" displays) to static and apparently that was the problem. I removed the static modifier and now it works fine. Sorry for wasting your time.

So be careful when using the static modifier.